# Remove particular String from NSArray not Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray, xcode7

I am new in IOS development.I am getting phone numbers in NSArray and this is something like this.

```
9429564999,
9428889239,
7878817072,
"+919408524477",
9909951666,
9879824567,
"+91 8469-727523",
"94-28-037780",
"+918460814614",
55246,
"8866-030880",
"95-37-223347",
"+919574777070",
"+917405750526",
```

Now i want to remove **-** and **+91** from NSArray List not whole object.How to do this Please someone help

Comment: What whole object? Clarify your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *phoneNoList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"9429564999",@"9428889239",@"7878817072",@"+919408524477",@"9909951666",@"9879824567", @"+91 8469-727523",@"94-28-037780",@"+918460814614",@"55246",@"8866-030880",@"95-37-223347",@"+919574777070", @"+917405750526", nil];
    NSMutableArray *noArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSString *no in phoneNoList) {
        NSString *temp1 = [[no componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                                   componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        if (temp1.length > 10) {
            NSString *temp=[temp1 substringFromIndex:2];
            [noArr addObject:temp];
        }
        else
            [noArr addObject:temp1];
    }

    NSLog(@"Arr Data : %@",noArr);
```

Try this, definitely helps to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (NSString *number in arrayName) {

number = [number stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+91"
                                     withString:@""] mutableCopy];


number = [number stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-"
                                     withString:@""] mutableCopy];
[arrayNameNew addObject:number];

}
```

Try like this :)

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (NSString *phoneNum in phoneNumArray) {
    phoneNum = [phoneNum stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+91" withString:@""];
    phoneNum = [phoneNum stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (NSString *str in arrayNumbers) {
    NSString *stringWithoutNineOne = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+91" withString:@""];
    NSString *stringWithoutSpace = [stringWithoutNineOne stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSString *stringWithoutdash = [stringWithoutSpace stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    [refinedArr addObject:stringWithoutdash];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove special characters from array.

```
for (NSString *strPhoneNo in arrayPhoneNo) {
    [self removeSpecialCharacter:strPhoneNo];
}
```

and

```
-(NSString*)removeSpecialCharacter:(NSString*)mobileNumber
{
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+91" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];

    // remove extra special charecter if needed.

    //mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    //mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    //mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    return mobileNumber;
}
```

if NSArray not update then use NSMutableArray insted of NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this....
Getting the last 10 digits of your given phone numbers.....if your requirement is fixed then try this single line code

```
for (NSString *string in arrayNumbers) {
NSString *trimmedString=[string substringFromIndex:MAX((int)[string length]-10, 0)];
[newArray addobject:trimmedString]
}
```